# complexity analysis for double loops

Tags: complexity-theory

If I have the following code in . net:

```
for i=0 to n
    for j=0 to n
        m=i*j
    next j
next i
```

so I have done the following complexity analysis:

[image]

is this correct? Also in which case a double loop could give a O(n) complexity?

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest case, the complexity of two nested loops is equal to the complexity of one loop multiplied by the complexity of the other. The demonstration is almost identical to what you posted.

Therefore, if you want the complexity of the two nested loops to be O(n), you could make one of the loops execute in constant time:

```
for i=0 to 10
  for j=0 to n
    m = i*j
  next j
next i
```

or you could have each of them execute in O(n^1/2):

```
for i=0 to sqrt(n)
  for j=0 to sqrt(n)
    m = i*j
  next j
next i
```

or other variations of the sort.

A particularly interesting solution could be when the number of iterations in the inner loop depends on the counter for the outer loop, but i don't have an example for you.